# HTML/CSS: Show an element on hover while the rest is blurred

Tags: html, css, hover

I’m making a portfolio and there are text blocks that get blurry when you hover mouse over them. The point is to make text «Learn More» to appear in that block while the rest of the text is blurry. I am struggling so much with it. Please help.

Here is my text block:

```
    <div class="card-body about-me-title ">
      <h5 class="text-center overlay"><a href="#">Learn More</a> </h5>
      <div class="blur-in">
        <h4 class="card-title  p-1 h1">
          <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right pl-1"></i>
          Self-taught
        </h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle text-white px-5 h2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Optio ipsa architecto quas explicabo necessitatibus.</h6>    
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the styles for it:

```
.about-me-title {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 50px;   
}

.card {
    border: none;
}   

.blur-in {
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);  
}

.blur-in:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
}

.overlay a{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

As you can see, «Learn More» text is there, but I want it to be hidden, and show on hover, so the whole text box becomes kind of a button on hover. I tried «visibility» and «display» properties, unsuccessfull.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about something like this?

```css
.about-me-title {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.card {
  border: none;
}

.blur-in {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
}

.blur-in:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
}

.overlay a {

  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 0em;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  /* transition effect. not necessary */
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}

.card-body:hover .overlay a {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body about-me-title ">
  <h5 class="overlay text-center"><a href="#">Learn More</a> </h5>
  <div class="blur-hover">
    <div class="blur-in">
      <h4 class="card-title  p-1 h1">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right pl-1"></i>
        Self-taught
      </h4>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle text-white px-5 h2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Optio ipsa architecto quas explicabo necessitatibus.</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I added an extra div called Blur-in and made sure to put the overlay text outside of that div, or else it would be blurred too. You can change the margins and positions and style of the overlay however you want.

No JS. Just the CSS and HTML.

**UPDATED:**

Here's a pure CSS solution. I don't know why I didn't think about this one before, but if you just move the  div up a tier, you can wrap all the text as a link. You also need to remove the Z-Index you added. Finally, just format the text so that it looks like what you want (see a {} in CSS, text/ link styling). Hope this helps!

```css
.about-me-title {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.card {
  border: none;
}

.blur-in {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);

}

.blur-in:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 0em;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

}

.card-body:hover .overlay {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;

}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body about-me-title ">
<a href="#">
  <h5 class="overlay text-center">Learn More</h5>
  <div class="blur-hover">
    <div class="blur-in">
      <h4 class="card-title  p-1 h1">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right pl-1"></i>
        Self-taught
      </h4>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle text-white px-5 h2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Optio ipsa architecto quas explicabo necessitatibus.</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: but the blur disappears as you hover over the link... ughh

Comment: The only thing I can think of with pure CSS is to just add a transition effect that keeps it it from changing back quickly. Probably not a production ready idea. But here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/23xdtqey/

Notice the transition: 0s 2s; on overlay and card-body, then again on blur-in. This is getting kind of hacky, but it might work if the intention is to have the user click the link anyway.  You should definitely look into simple javascript for this, that would be my official recommendation.

Comment: Hey there - After thinking about it a bit, I realized there actually is one pure CSS/HTML solution that I think would be acceptable. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with jQuery? I think using .hide() and .show() or .hover() methods could help you achieve this behavior. It could be something like this.

```
$('.text-center').hover(() => {
  $(this).toggle();
});
```

Probably toggle is not the correct method but it could help to see the "hide/show" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

HTML File

```css
    .about-me-title {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 50px;   
}

.card {
    border: none;
}   

.blur-in {
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);  
}

.blur-in:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
}

.overlay a{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 2em;
    -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
    color: RGBA(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
}

.Learn-More:hover{
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  color: RGBA(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="card-body about-me-title ">
      <h5 class="text-center overlay"><a href="#" class="Learn-More">Learn More</a> </h5>
      <div class="blur-in">
        <h4 class="card-title  p-1 h1">
          <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right pl-1"></i>
          Self-taught
        </h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle text-white px-5 h2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Optio ipsa architecto quas explicabo necessitatibus.</h6>    
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```